# Injecting json using angular with working html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I need your help! I'm trying to import json file using angular. The only problem is that the json file is imported from other website and the html tags display as normal text. And here is my question, is there any chance to make those tags normal html not a visible text?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="lightblue">
        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainController">
            <div id="content" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: green; ">
                <div ng-repeat="content in contents">
                    <h2>{{content.title}}</h2>
                    <p>{{content.date}}</p>
                    <p>{{content.info}}</p>
                    <p>{{content.content}}</p>
                    <p>{{content.url}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

maincontroller.js

```
var myapp=angular.module('mainApp',['ngSanitize']);
myapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/WP/?json=get_recent_posts').then(function(response, date){
        $scope.contents = response.data.posts;
        alert("success");
        console.log(response)
    }, function(error){
        $scope.contents = [{title:"<h4> Error </h4>",date:"<p> JSON invalid </p>"}]; 
        alert("error");
        console.log(response)
    })
});
```

Comment: not able to understand from your description, what exactly do you want. Some example would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution :

**Your maincontroller.js file**

I have added `$sce.trustAsHtml`so html file can know that content has html tags

```
 var myapp=angular.module('mainApp',['ngSanitize']);
    myapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http, $sce){
        $http.get('http://localhost/wordpress/?json=get_recent_posts').then(function(response, date){
            $scope.contents = response.data.posts;
            $scope.info = $sce.trustAsHtml(contents.info);
            alert("success");
            console.log(response);
        }, function(error){
            $scope.contents = [{title:"<h4> Error </h4>",date:"<p> JSON invalid </p>"}]; 
            alert("error");
            console.log(response);
        })
    });
```

And your **index.html**

add `angular-sanitize.js` file if you have not added yet. and use `ng-bind-html` in your html tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="mainController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="lightblue">
        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainController">
            <div id="content" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: green; ">
                <div ng-repeat="content in contents">
                    <h2 ng-bind-html="content.title">{{content.title}}</h2>
                    <p>{{content.date}}</p>
                    <p>{{content.info}}</p>
                    <p ng-bind-html="content.content">{{content.content}}</p>
                    <p>{{content.url}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using binding express `{{}}` use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` It will render html tag as well

example

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.text = "<strong>this is html</strong>";
});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Hello {{name}}!
  <br/>
  <ul>
    <li>{{text}}</li>
    <li ng-bind-html-unsafe="text"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Out will be like

```
Hello World! 
<strong>this is html</strong>
this is html
```

Comment: Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood well, you have to use something like this in your javascript:

```
myapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http, $sce){
    $http.get('/WP/?json=get_recent_posts').then(function(response, date){
         $scope.contents = response.data.posts;
         $scope.title = $sce.trustAsHtml(contents.title);
         alert("success");
         console.log(response)
    }, function(error){
         $scope.title = $sce.trustAsHtml("<h4> Error </h4>");
         $scope.date = $sce.trustAsHtml("<p> JSON invalid      </p>");
         alert("error");
        console.log(response)
    })
});
```

and this in your html:

```
<p ng-bind-html="title" class="htmlComment">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). Edit your code like below

```
<span ng-bind-html="content.title">{{content.title}}</span>
```

Comment: tired it before, but still got some bugs, but thanks for help anyway :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

https://plnkr.co/edit/JcW2fxcISsjYKpXGBBkp?p=preview

Inject ngSanitize before using ngBindHtml

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);....

<div ng-bind-html="scopeVariable"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome Lapiso :)